# Captaris vs K2 comparison

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, k2, captaris

I’m trying to find some objective comparisons of Captaris and K2 workflow products. I haven’t been able to find anything through the usual channels so if anyone out there has an understanding of both products I’d really like to hear from you. I’m primarily interested in the pros and cons of each for use with ASP.NET and also with SharePoint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of actually completing this question and providing an answer, there are no comparisons! At best there are several mentions of the two in the same sentence but these are many years old and certainly don’t rate as objective comparisons. Captaris is also now OpenText Workflow Server.

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a good fight Troy :)

A couple years ago I was trying to answer the same question but we had Ultimus as the main option. At the time I found an even older PDF file with a few info (http://www.scribd.com/doc/6910318/DOt-Net-FAQ24) but we ended up getting their sales reps  to give formal presentations.

We ended up with Ultimus for that project, but a few months later I saw a presentation from Nintex and it was interesting too, even tho the project related to it did not came thru.